# Unable to unzip file in node.js using zlib module

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I have created a zip file of a .txt file using node.js zlib and while trying to unzip the file i used the same node_module zlib but its throwing error.Please check my code snippet and please feel free to edit code.I also checked the file location its same as the

**Error :**

> Error: unexpected end of file
>       at Unzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)

**Code :**

```
    const fs=require('fs');
    const zlib = require('zlib');  
    const iii = fs.createReadStream('test.txt.gz');
    const oo = fs.createWriteStream('test1.txt');  
    const unzip = zlib.createUnzip()  
    iii.pipe(unzip).pipe(oo)
```

I am unable to understand my mistake.Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks in advance!!

Used below code to zip the file.

**code to zip:**

```
const fs=require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');  
const gzip = zlib.createGzip();  

const inp = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');  
const out = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt.gz');  
inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

Comment: What is the size and content of that file ? Are you able to unpack that file by using any commandline utility ?

Comment: Its very small file 287 bytes file  after compression its showing size is 0 bytes.

Comment: If it is of size zero there is no point in trying to unpack. I guess the file is just corrupted. And thats why you get that error message. Post the other part of code where you pack that file

Comment: Ok will check again.

Comment: It worked I re-compressed the same file and tried its working now thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting an error because the file got corrupted while trying the zip-unzip.
There was no error in the code. 
So after deleting and recreating zip file,  i was able to unzip it.

**Note:**

Whenever you try something like this,if you get such error, then always check **file size** it should **not be zero**. If it is zero,then recreate the zip and try again.